# Parsear DATE con datos provenientes de un JSON

Tags: java, android, date, parsear

Que tal hoy tuve un problemilla con un parseo `Date` estoy trayendo datos de un servicio hasta aquí todo bien, bueno tengo un campo en cual me trae un `Date`
con el siguiente formato

`2017-01-05 11:11:00`

Ahora este valor me toma error en mi `codigo`, teniendo **evento** como modelo y `jEvento` como un `JSONARRAY`

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", new Locale("es", "pe"));
        try {
         evento.setFecha_inicio(sdf.parse(jEventos.getJSONObject(i).getString("EVE_FEC_INICIO")+".000000"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Como verán he agregado `+".000000"` no creo que sea una buena práctica, ahora mi duda es si seguir con este código o modificar el tipo de variable en mi base de datos.
Quizás alguien tenga una mejor forma de trabajar esto. Gracias.

Comment: Cual es el error que obtienes?

Comment: Obtenía un error antes de haber agregado el `+".000000"` a mi código, una excepción xq sin ese pedazo de código no quería parsear

Comment: La razón es que la fecha en el json, originalmente venía sin milisegundos y tu formato estaba definido como: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS" , un formato definido como : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" sería suficiente.

Comment: Lo sospeché desde un principio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitivamente lo ideal es que tengas un formato uniforme de datos en el .json, por ejemplo:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Además no veo ningún caso definir un formato que contiene mili segundos:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
```

cuando siempre estas definiendo los mili segundos como :

```
".000000"
```

---

La razón del problema es que la fecha en el json, originalmente venía sin milisegundos y el formato estaba definido como:
 `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"`

un formato definido como :

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

sería suficiente.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Locale("es", "pe"));
```